# Обособление зависимой части в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Уважаемые знатоки русского языка! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Есть следующее предложение: "Получите более подробную информацию, связавшись с нами по телефону, или же оставьте заявку на сайте."
Вопрос: нужна ли запятая после слова информация?
Еще с уроков русского языка в школе помню так: получите (как именно?) - связавшись с нами по телефону. Следовательно, часть "связавшись с нами по телефону" должна обособляться. 
Но чутье подсказывает, что что-то не так! 
Помогите разобраться и, если не сложно, дайте развернутый ответ!
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

С пунктуационной точки зрения вы написали верно:

> Получите более подробную информацию, связавшись с нами по телефону, или же оставьте заявку на сайте.

"Связавшись с нами по телефону" — это **деепричастный оборот** (отвечает на вопрос *что сделав?*), с обеих сторон выделяется запятыми.

А теперь об изъянах предложения.

1. **Первое слово можно прочитать двумя способами**: "полу́чите" (будущее время) и "получи́те" (повелительное наклонение). Обе формы не очень уместны: будущее время предсказывает будущее (откуда автору предложения знать, позвонит ли клиент?), повелительное предложение несколько бестактно (кто автор предложения такой, чтобы приказывать клиенту?). По-моему, в аналогичных случаях чаще пишут "можете получить...".
2. **Результат второго действия неоднозначен**: что будет, если клиент оставит заявку на сайте? Вероятно, вы свяжетесь с ним по телефону, и он и в этом случае сможет получить "более подробную информацию", поэтому логичнее использовать и для звонка по телефону, и для заявки на сайте одну форму.
3. **Частица *же* избыточна**: ни к чему усилять разницу между вариантами, между ними нет принципиального различия.

Итого:

> Вы можете получить более подробную информацию, связавшись с нами по телефону или оставив заявку на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

> "Получите более подробную информацию, связавшись с нами по телефону,
>   или же оставьте заявку на сайте."

Я бы написал так:

*Более подробную информацию можете получить, связавшись с нами по телефону  или (же) оставив заявку на сайте.*

Comment: Да, повелительное наклонение у наших рекламщиков в крови. Хорошо ещё, что не "тыкают" :)